# Is it possible to make sql statement using reflection and LINQ together?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to make a generic query builder for entity framework.

before reading my code 
`GetPropValue("PropertyName")` is an object extension method that returns the value of the property with that name;

```
private void MyGenerateQuery()
    {          
       //loContext refers to parent table
        var loContext = (DbSet<TEntity>)Context.GetPropValue(boName);

       var queryable = loContext
                .Join(
                    (DbSet<ORDERS>)Context.GetPropValue("ORDERS"),
                    par => par.GetPropValue("CB_REFNO"),
                    chld => chld.GetPropValue("OR_M_REFNO"),
                    (par, chld) => new { GetPropValue = chld.GetPropValue("OR_DESC") }
                );

            myGridView1.DataSource = queryable.ToList();                     
    }
```

so when my code hits to the bottom line

```
myGridView1.DataSource = queryable.ToList();
```

I get the following error message:
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetPropValue(System.Object, System.String)' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

what should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection here? You know all the entities needed?

Comment: you can use Linqkit to generate queryable exptession. https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

Comment: Use [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), that's what they are designed for. LINQKit that M. Rezaeyan mentioned makes them easier to use.

Comment: Yes, I will know all entities needed, this function will be held in my parent class, in fact what I want to do is, pass the relations to the parent class and inside a recursive loop add those joins and than return the list to my BindingSource.DataSource, but I get the above error